# Why does highcharts sankey chart sometimes combine multiple nodes with same node name but different Id into one and hide the lines?

Tags: javascript, highcharts, sankey-diagram

For the below snippet,

```
const data = [
  {"from":"step2_FRANCE","to":"step3_SPAIN","weight": 2},
  {"from":"step3_SPAIN","to":"step4_PORTUGAL","weight":2},
  {"from":"step2_PORTUGAL","weight":1, to: "step3_SPAIN" },
  {"from":"step2_FRANCE","weight":1},
  {"from":"step2_SPAIN","weight":1},
  {"from":"step2_ENG","weight":1},
  {"from":"step2_PORTUGAL","weight":1, to: "step3_SPAIN"},
  {"from":"step2_FRANCE","weight":1},
];

const nodes = [
  {"id":"step2_PORTUGAL","name":"Portugal","column":1, "color":"#ede042"},
  {"id":"step2_FRANCE","name":"France","column":1, "color":"#cb65dc"},
  {"id":"step2_SPAIN","name":"Spain","column":1,, "color":"#6493f1"},
  {"id":"step2_ENG","name":"England", "column":1, "color":"#6ed4eb"},
  {"id":"step3_SPAIN","name":"Spain","column":2, "color":"#6493f1"},
  {"id":"step4_PORTUGAL","name":"Portugal","column":3, "color":"#ede042"}
];


Highcharts.chart('container', {
  title: {
    text: 'Highcharts Sankey Diagram'
  },
  accessibility: {
    point: {
      valueDescriptionFormat: '{index}. {point.from} to {point.to}, {point.weight}.'
    }
  },
  series: [{
    data,
    nodes,
    type: 'sankey',
    name: 'Sankey demo series'
  }]
});
```

I get an output like this: [image: Incorrect sankey chart output]
I was expecting:

1. France, Portugal, Spain and England in column 1 (ids with step2_..)
2. Spain in column 2 (ids with step3_..)
3. Portugal in column 3 (ids with step4_..)

In the `nodes` option the column number and names are also present.

If I comment out one of the nodes from `Step2..`, I get a partially correct graph.

```
const nodes = [
{"id":"step2_PORTUGAL","name":"Portugal","column":1,"color":"#ede042"},
// {"id":"step2_FRANCE","name":"France","column":1, "color":"#cb65dc"},
{"id":"step2_SPAIN","name":"Spain","column":1, "color":"#6493f1"},
{"id":"step2_ENG","name":"England", "column":1, "color":"#6ed4eb"},
{"id":"step3_SPAIN","name":"Spain","column":2, "color":"#6493f1"}, 
 {"id":"step4_PORTUGAL","name":"Portugal","column":3, "color":"#ede042"}
];
```

[image: Partially correct sankey chart]

I am not able to understand why the chart behaves this way. I am guessing there's something wrong in the way I'm passing data/nodes. It's much appreciated if someone could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting setting the columns from 0 in your node options solves the problem.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/fkshbmdv/

```
const nodes = [{
    "id": "step2_PORTUGAL",
    "name": "Portugal",
    //"column": 0,
    "color": "#ede042"
  }, ...
];
```

Actually using the column property is unnecessary in this case: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/n53Ljcgd/

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.sankey.nodes.column